# typescript error with styled components css function

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I'm getting this error `{ expected ts(2322)` when using the CSS function from styled-components

like it's shown here:

[image]

the error is going away when putting the template literal on one line!

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a vscode extension.
disabling the extension solved the problem!